# Node Debug serverless offline using vscode

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, serverless-framework, serverless-offline

I am using VS Code for development of AWS Lambda functions, I started using the serverless framework and the serverless offline library but, I am unable to use VS Code's debug mode to locally debug the code.

I am referring many sites, Following is one of them:
https://medium.com/@OneMuppet_/debugging-lambada-functions-locally-in-vscode-with-actual-break-points-deee6235f590

My project structure is as follows:

[image]

`Package.json`:

[image]

`launch.json`:

[image]

I get the following error when I start debug:

[image]

Can someone please guide, with the correct configuration?

Comment: what does your launch.json config look like?

Comment: @joeCarpenter updated the question with launch.json

Comment: Thank you Aniruddha. Still not able to get it going

Answer (score 10):

in the package.json add debug script:

```
"scripts": {
.......
    "debug": "node --inspect node_modules/serverless/bin/serverless offline -s dev",
.........
}
```

VS code lunch.json

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "name": "Serverless",
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "run",
        "debug"
      ],
      "port": 9229
    }
  ]
}
```

Then start debugging from VS code

Comment: Why on vscode output panel I wont get the same logging msgs as  I would on a normal terminal session?

Answer (score 4):

The warning you are seeing is a deprecation warning; [the legacy debugger (--debug) has been deprecated since Node 7.7.0](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/#legacy-debugger). The correct way to attach a node debugger to serverless offline is by using `--inspect`:

```sh
node --inspect $(npm bin)/sls offline start
```

Comment: with this I get the the Debugger listening, however how do I actually get my debugging profile configured?

Comment: Do I put this in the debug script in package.json?

Comment: @AniruddhaRaje yeah, you can replace the `debug` script in `package.json`.

Comment: hmmm ok, so what does $(npm bin) mean? I tried to run that exact code but no luck.

Comment: thanks, it was exactly the answer I needed!

Comment: try using $(which sls) offline

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid sample event in JSON format AND you are OK with debugging one function at a time, then here is a configuration that has worked great for me. It enables breakpoints and step-through debuggin exactly as you'd expect:

```json
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "name": "sls invoke local: myFunction",
      "runtimeExecutable": "sls",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "invoke",
        "local",
        "-f",
        "loadOptions",
        "-p",
        "activities/myFunction/myFunction-event.json"
      ],
    },
```